# Convert values in form box

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-slider

I'm a bit confused on how this works.  I am trying to have the seconds value convereted to a "hh:mm:ss" in the input box when the slider is active.

Here the div displays the start time and end time in seconds.  And adjusts as they slide

```
    <div class='slider-example col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-5 center-block'>
        <div class="well">

                <input id="ex2" type="text" class="span2" value="[{{ start_length }},{{ end_length }}]" data-slider-min="{{ start_length }}" data-slider-max="{{ end_length }}" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="[{{ start_length }},{{ end_length }}]" data-slider-selection="after" data-slider-tooltip="hide"/>
            </div> <!-- /well -->
        </div> <!-- /slider example -->
                 <div class = "container col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-5 center-block">
                    <form class="form-inline">
                    <div class = "container col-xs-4">
                     <div class="form-group">

                        <label for="bar">Start:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control"  id="bar">

                     </div>
                            </div>
<div class = "container col-xs-4 pull-right">
                     <div class="form-group">

                        <label for="bar1">End: </label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control"  id="bar1">

                    </div>
                        </div>

                    </form>
                 </div>
```

Here is my javascript

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="{{url_for('static', filename='js/bootstrap-slider.js')}}"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>

    function secondsTimeSpanToHMS(s) {
        var h = Math.floor(s/3600);
        s -= h*3600;
        var m = Math.floor(s/60);
        s -= m*60;
        return h+":"+(m < 10 ? '0'+m : m)+":"+(s < 10 ? '0'+s : s);
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){

        /* Example 2 */
        $("#ex2").slider({});
        $("#ex2").on('slide', function (ev) {
                $('#bar').val(ev.value.slice(",")[0]);
                $('#bar1').val(ev.value.slice(",")[1]);
        document.getElementById('#bar').innerHTML = secondsTimeSpanToHMS('#bar');
        document.getElementById('#bar1').innerHTML = secondsTimeSpanToHMS('#bar1');
     });

    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt it's doing what you intended, but here's what it's trying to do

```
 $("#ex2").on('slide', function (ev) {
```

The slide event triggers when you slide the range handles and returns a 2 element array with the value of each handle

```
         $('#bar').val(ev.value.slice(",")[0]);
         $('#bar1').val(ev.value.slice(",")[1]);
```

This is an attempt to set the value of the element with id bar and bar1 to the range handle values - this will work if bar and bar1 are form elements (like a textbox, textarea...)

```
         document.getElementById('#bar').innerHTML = ...              
         document.getElementById('#bar1').innerHTML = ...
```

This *attempts* to set the innerHTML of elements with id #bar and #bar1 - however since you are using `document.getElementById`, you should be using bar and bar1 instead of prefixing it with # (like you'd do for jQuery).

```
         ... = secondsTimeSpanToHMS('#bar');
         ... = secondsTimeSpanToHMS('#bar1');
```

I'd assume the above is an attempt to run the function using the range handle values, but the code is wrongly passing in jQuery selectors to these function - the function expects a value in seconds.

Finally, the `secondsTimeSpanToHMS` takes a seconds value and converts it to hour:minute:seconds

---

The below may be a bit closer to what you are looking for

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    /* Example 2 */
    $("#ex2").slider({});
    $("#ex2").on('slide', function (ev) {
        $('#bar').val(secondsTimeSpanToHMS(ev.value.slice(",")[0]));
        $('#bar1').val(secondsTimeSpanToHMS(ev.value.slice(",")[1]));
    });
});
```

Or alternatively, you could set **another** 2 element's innerHTML to the output of `secondsTimeSpanToHMS` and retain the .val() lines from the original function.

Comment: Well this makes me understand a bit more.  I just updated the question with the div regarding the text boxes.  But I still am confused, so I should replace `document.getElementById('#bar').innerHTML = ... ` with `document.getElementById('bar').innerHTML = ... ` as well as `... = secondsTimeSpanToHMS('#bar');`?

Comment: 1. document.getElementById needs and ID, not a selector i.e. you don't need the #, 2. it doesn't sound right that you are setting the element bar / bar1 value to seconds and the set the same element's innerHTML to something else - you probably want different elements. 3. secondsTimeSpanToHMS expects a number to be passed in not a selector i.e. you should be doing something like secondsTimeSpanToHMS(<some number>); like ev.value.slice(",")[1]